# Check if user has already sent data to server?

Tags: matrix, server, usermanager

I'm developing an app which will send data to a server about exam results which have been taken by the user, what would be the  best solution at the server side to check if the user has already sent it's results to the server.
I was thinking of a matrix of user and exam rows and columns and was about to create this matrix with a database, what would you suggest me to do?